# WebView reload not working - Android

Tags: android, webview

I have an Activity lets say Activity A. This only has a webview element that loads a jQuery List from an html page from server. On the header of this page i have a filter button. This opens up another activity which have checkboxes to click in order to filter the List.

The way i filter this list is that when the "Done" button on the filterActivity is clicked i Post an HTTP Message to server and i call the finish() method like this:

```
if(!checked.isEmpty()){
            Log.v("HTTP_POST","Executing...");
            new HttpPostFilter(checked).execute();
        }

finish();
```

On ActivityA i call the onResume method:

```
public void onResume(){
    Log.v("RESUME","OnResume called");
    super.onResume();
    myWebView.reload();
}
```

However the webpage doesnot show the filtered list with or without the `reload()` method. It only shows the full list as before. There is no problem with the Http POST implementation as from LogCat i can view the responsemessage which is OK.